# How to edit .java files imported in Eclipse from a .jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, import, jar, export

I have a question, perhaps it was already answered, but i didn't manage to find it and I appologize if the solution already exists (let me know if it is before deleting my thread).

Problem is: 
I have created a program on another PC and exported it from eclipse as a .jar file. It works on my main PC when I double click on it but when I import it in Eclipse I can't find the .java file. So i can't edit it.

What I have done so far:

1. In eclipse I have created a new empty project
2. I have right clicked,import, archive file, selected the .class files that eclipse sees, but when I am in the Project Explorer in Eclipse I can't find the .java file where the main is. I mean I can click run as a program and it works, but there is no .java file, only .class files. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

That cranes.class should be cranes.java. At least on my other PC it is.
Program works fine, but I can't edit it on my main PC. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks and best regards

Comment: the `.class` file is the compiled version, i.e. the bytecode-translation, of some `.java`-file. You can reverse-engineer the code (IntelliJ, for example, has a tool baked-in to reverse engineer code), but you cannot modify it without furhter tooling, e.g. [Byte Buddy](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the `Export Java source files and resources` option while creating the `jar` file and then your Java files will be available on importing the project from the `jar` file.

[image]

Comment: As per question he wants to edit those files in second project. You method will export the source code along with jar (of first project) but this wont allow it to change it in the second project.

Comment: yes. that's the problem. I created the program on my laptop and wanted to import it in my desktop so I can further modify it. I thought I exported it correctly but apparently did not flag the "export java source files". I will try that and let you know if there is an issue. I did not knew that once exported the source code is protected like that. I guess it's nice because other people can't steal your data

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to how you use other **libraries**. You depend on the **Jar** file which contains class **bytecode** (compiled) of java code. You **can't** edit any of such files directly in the project you are using it. Thought you can always **extends** functionalities in your current project using simple **inheritance** concepts.

If you think such functionalities are **trivial** you should prefer to change in the original project **rebuild** the jar and use the **newer** version of jar.

> However if you feel similar things for **3rd party** library you can
>   always make changes after taking fork from those library **source**
>   code (if **open source**) and build and use your **own version** or go
>   ahead and raise **pull request** if you are confident about your
>   changes.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly when you build a jar file, all you have in it are .class files; these are the result of compiling .java files, and so are not editable with text editors.

You CAN create a jar file that contains .java (also known as source) files, and even a jar file that contains both .java and .class files, but if you ask eclipse to create a jar file, by default it is just going to put .class files and files from resource folders in it, not .java files.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from the question, the jar is a library created by OP, by compiling java files into class files and packing/exporting them. Although the class files can't be edited in any IDE, they **can** be de-compiled into Java files by using third-party applications. 

I personally use IntelliJ for this de-compiling source files **authored by me**

**Note:** Although this gives OP the desired functionality, it may lead to violations if the classes are Copyrighted.

As IntelliJ states, they neither encourage nor discourage de-compiling class files and the decision is purely to the user's discretion. 

EDIT: It is always recommended to use the original source files for editing. Try to host them on git so that it may be retrieved anytime required

Answer (score 0):

It may be simpler to not use eclipse but jar/zip/tar your project directory on the one computer and simply extract it onto the other, then open that folder as a new project in Eclipse.

Best is the suggestion from @SanjayBharathi to use git and clone the repo on your other machine.